# Mutual impedance of two parallel dipole

Tags: impedance, antenna-modeling, parallel-dipole

Good Morning all,

I want to calculate the mutual impedance of two parallel dipole.

The first hypothesis is to assume that the dipole 2 is in open circuit, nothing difficult here I knew how to do it
[image]

Hypothesis 2 is to assume that dipole 2 is short circuited or loaded with some impedance

Are there equations for hypothesis 2, or is there a parameter to add or modify on Baker's equations?

thank you

Comment: Welcome!  and keep asking good questions.

Comment: Please, tell us where you found the graph that appears in your question.

Comment: @BrianK1LI It's in Balanis, Antenna Theory, Analysis and Design, 2nd ed, p419. Apart from using NEC, there are closed-form solutions for trivial cases (parallel and collinear), for feedpoints at the current maxima, for half-wave dipoles with sinusoidal current. The equations are large, I could re-type them if you really can't find them.

Comment: @BrianK1LI : I got the graph by integrating baker's equations : Digital computation of the mutual impedance between thin dipoles ( ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/1137835), and there are multiple configurations

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think if you're worried about the *load* on the other dipole, you need to go back and look at how [Z parameters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impedance_parameters) work.

$Z_{21}$ doesn't assume anything about the impedance on the two dipoles. It's just one of the impedance parameter term - $Z_{21}$ is the voltage developed on dipole 2 *due to* a current in dipole 1. It's not the final voltage or current present on dipole 2, for that you need to know other things.
I can't find the equations online, they're in any good electromagnetics book, I can't find mine either.

To calculate the *input impedance* on port 1, you need to consider the impedance on port 2, whether that's a short or an open.

So if you know $Z_{11}$ (self-impedance of the dipole alone), $Z_{21}$ (mutual impedance from the equation, same as $Z_{12}$ in a passive system), and $Z_{22}$ (self-impedance of dipole 2) and choose $Z_L$, then

[image: Zin equation from wikipedia]

This is how you can calculate the currents on a yagi antenna, for example, without resorting to numerical methods. [Wikipedia Yagi Antenna](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yagi%E2%80%93Uda_antenna#Analysis) actually has a nice section about this, now that I scratch a bit.

Comment: thanks a lot @tomnexus, that helped me alot